# How to change background color of a single mat step icon?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

```
 <mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper>
        <mat-step class="red-stepper">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>
                <span>Step 1</span>
            </ng-template>
        </mat-step>
        <mat-step class="red-stepper">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>
                <span>step 2</span>
            </ng-template>
        </mat-step>
        <mat-step>
            <ng-template matStepLabel>
                <span>Step 3</span>
            </ng-template>
        </mat-step>
        <mat-step>
            <ng-template matStepLabel>
                <span>Step 4</span>
            </ng-template>
        </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

For example I have here 4 mat-steps, but I want to change the color of the first two of them, how can I achieve this? I know how to change the selected one, but this is not the case.

I've tried applying the bg color of the stepper in different classes but with no success.

```
.red-stepper {
    .mat-step-icon {
        span.ng-star-inserted {
            background-color: red !important;
        }
    }
    background-color: red !important;
    .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon {
        background-color: #007FAD !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to apply style in a parent component try :

```
:host {
  ::ng-deep {
    mat-step {
      &.red-stepper {
        background-color: #000;
      }
    }
  }
}
```